# S3 file reading in chuck error

Tags: php, file, amazon-s3

I have video files stored on S3. and want to read the file in chunks (1mb). I am using the following code.

```
$file = env('S3_URL').$post->video; // complete video URL saved on S3 bucket
$fp  = fopen($file, 'r');
$segment_id = 0;
while (! feof($fp)) {
    $chunk = fread($fp, 1048576); // 1MB per chunk for this sample
    $segment_id++;
    echo "\nsegment :".$segment_id;
}
fclose($fp);
```

But this loop never ends.

Answer (score 0):

Use S3 [API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html) to interact with S3 objects.

```
$result = $client->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => 'data.txt'
));
$result['Body']->rewind();
while ($data = $result['Body']->read(1024)) {
    echo $data;
}
```

There is an example already given to read data using streams [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#downloading-objects)